# Ember JS, updating array not reflecting in views

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Updating Ember JS array is not reflecting in views.

Controller

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  results: [],
  init: function(){
    _this = this
    App.MyModel.find({}).then(function(contents) {
      obj1 = contents.objectAt(0)
      obj1.get('data').hasMany.results.forEach(function(item){
          _this.results.push(item)
      });
    })
    //rest of the code
  }
})
```

Template

```
{{#each results}}
  // show items of reults.
{{/each}}
```

This is the piece of code in which i am fetching data from server, and upon its loading, i am pushing it into results array.
This loading for data from server takes some time, so template maps over the empty results array. Ideally, results array should update the things in template but logically it shouldn't.

Does any body know where i am missing? or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For bindings to work you have to use `pushObject` instead of `push`.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  results: [],
  init: function(){
    _this = this;
    App.MyModel.find({}).then(function(contents) {
      obj1 = contents.objectAt(0);
      obj1.get('data').hasMany.results.forEach(function(item){
        _this.results.pushObject(item)
      });
    })
    //rest of the code
  }
});
```

Fore more info on ember array `pushObject` please see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObjects).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that your array needs to be an `Ember.NativeArray`, which is also a `MutableArray`.   If you are having ember extend the native js Array prototype, then the native js array will have a `.pushObject(thing)` function. If you aren't extending the native prototype you will need to use `Ember.A([])`. [More about Ember.A()](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/functions/@ember%2Farray/A)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The problem is that Ember doesn't get notified about the change in the array. In this case you have a special Ember function (pushObject) that replaces the standard Push and also notifies the framework of the change. But in other cases (for example Array.splice) you don't have such function, so you need to notify the framework manually. You can do this with:

```
this.notifyPropertyChange('array');
```